# mcrypt_decrypt not returning correct data only when used in Laravel seeding

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, mcrypt, laravel-seeding

We are using the built in Database Seeding in Laravel 5.3 under PHP 7.0 on Windows.  Problem is that whenever we use mcrypt_encrypt to encrypt some data, the data we get back from mcrypt_decrypt is not the same as what we passed in.

```
$data = @mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, self::$key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0");

$data = @mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, self::$key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0");
```

In this case, $data is some binary string and not the original string.

- This **only** happens during seeding.  mcrypt_encrypt/mcrypt_decrypt will work through a web request or tinker.
- We know it's deprecated.  We have to use mcrypt_encrypt as opposed to the more recent encrypt (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/encryption), because we have legacy data already encrypted using mcrypt_encrypt.
- $key is a static variable that loads from an encryption key
- This is no error or warning to indicate a problem

Anybody have an idea of what could be going on here?

Comment: No you do not need to use mcrypt because data was encrypted with it, AES (which is what RIJNDAEL_128 is) is a standard and can be decrypted by other AES implementations. The one issue is the padding will have to be handled in your code.

Comment: FYI, to replicate `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`, `MCRYPT_MODE_CFB` with OpenSSL, use 'aes-128-cfb8' as the method.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback from zaph and some soul searching, we are going to migrate our encrypted data and use something more modern.  We've been avoiding it, because it still works in most cases.  But we're just postponing the inevitable.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.